# Слово «пока» — какая часть речи?

Tags: грамматика, части-речи

Прощание "пока" — это какая часть речи?

Answer (score 2):

**Из словаря**

ПОКА.  III. **частица**. Разг. До свидания. Ну, я пошёл, пока!

Answer (score 2):

Слово ***пока*** разные лингвисты квалифицируют по-разному.

Одни (Кузнецов, Зализняк) относят его к **частицам**.

Другие слово ***пока***, наряду со словами и словосочетаниями *Привет. Добрый день. Спокойной ночи. До свидания. Пожалуйста. Спасибо.* и др., относят к **коммуникативам.**

Из [Панова Г.И. ***"Морфология русского языка: Энциклопедический словарь-справочник"***, М., 2010]:

> Впервые коммуникативы как "особый лексико-грамматический класс слов"
>   выделил В. Ф. Киприянов. Основанием для объединения таких единиц *"в
>   один класс служит их специфическая синтаксическая функция ―  они
>   выступают как самостоятельные интонационно оформленные нечленимые
>   фразы…"* (Е.А. Земская).

Но всё же чаще подобные слова относят к **междометиям** (этикетным междометиям). Так квалифицирует их  и [**Грамматика-80**:](http://rusgram.narod.ru/1689-1705.html)

> **§ 1704.** К междометиям, обслуживающим сферу этикета, относятся
>   такие слова, как *здравствуй(те), до свиданья, спасибо, благодарю,
>   благодарствуй(те)* (устар.), *прости* (устар., поэт.), *прощай(те),
>   извини(те), прости(те), пожалуйста, всего хорошего, всего* (разг.),
>   *мое почтение, привет* (разг.), *здорово* (прост.), ***пока*** (разг.).

Разговорным **междометием** (с оттенком фамильярности) слово ***пока*** названо и в вышедшем в этом году ***"Большом универсальном словаре русского языка" под ред. Морковкина В.В.***

См.:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Междометием ***пока*** называется и в словаре [**Ефремовой:**](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/219768/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0)

> **IV** *межд. разг.*
>
> Употребляется как приветствие при прощании; соответствует по значению
>   слову: *до свидания.*

Comment: Самым разумным решением  было бы выделить слова этикета в отдельную группу (кстати, они вроде бы раньше рассматривались в теме вводных слов). Чтобы считать их междометиями, надо обратиться к определению междометий. Междометия выражают чувства, не называя их. А этикетные слова вполне информативны, особых чувств не выражают.

Comment: Плодить сущности не лучший выход.